# modify request.query_params in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to modify request.query_params from the django view, to add new parameters
I send a request

```
   / api / users /? search = users
```

from my view I get

```
   request.query_params
```

which returns a querydict, well what I want is to add search = users to request.query_params but from my view, any ideas?

[image: code]

Comment: request.query_params is simply a wrapper for request.GET

Comment: already modify the parameters in request.GET ["search"] = "users", but when I consult the values in request.query_params, the variables are not reflected

Comment: Clearly you haven't read the duplicate question and it's ansers

Comment: review the question, even if it does not solve my question, attached image